# Maximum distance of vectors

Tags: geometry

Hi I've list of vectors like: $(2,-2)$, $(-2,2)$, $(0,2)$, $(3,1)$, $(-3,1)$.

I need to compute max distance that I get from this vectors from  $(0,0)$.

I'm looking for general rule how to designate it.

@Edit

We start from the 0,0. So we go $0,2$ -> $3,1$ -> $2,-2$ and we're on $5,1$. So distance beetwen $0,0$ and $5,1$ $= 26$

Comment: please correct your notation.

Comment: the answer is 26. Look my edit